# To get fast result of mysql queries what should be need to upgrade either Google SQL CLOUD or Google COMPUTE Engine

Tags: php, mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

My database is on Google Cloud SQL with Second generation master with 1vcpu and 3.75 memory.

And I choose to google compute engine for php+mysql web app for this LAMP setup is done. I connected google cloud SQL with a compute engine. I have PHP files connected with google cloud SQL DATABASE. But the speed of the result is very very slow. How I can rectify this.

Comment: Could you please define "very very slow" ? This is very relative, so I would ask you to provide some tests results, as well as the querying you are trying to use.

Comment: query is :- select * from table1 where sample="samplename"; This single query is  not giving any result after an hour also .

Comment: Could you please check the Stackdriver logs and see if there is any error? In case you got no response for more than one hour, probably there should be an error, or a timeout in there. How are you doing you connection?

Comment: I'm not sure that is an issue of Cloud SQL. Check your database configuration, indexes and required flags by your application. Something is misconfigured. If you need help, open a support case. Google Experts could answer you

Comment: following error is showing in mysql error log:-    2019-11-15T07:07:49.569464Z 4688 [Note] Aborted connection 4688 to db: 'mpgen' user: 'seema' host: '34.83.166.7' (Got timeout writing communication packets)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And how are you trying to do your connections? What kind of service is connecting to your Cloud SQL instance?

Comment: I am connecting through Compute Engine .

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem and the quickest way to solve it is to move the DB from Google Cloud SQL. We now have our's in compute engine. It would be awesome if anyone has been able to rectify this problem and am sure Google engineers know about this problem.

Comment: mysql db in google compute engine is giving good speed ?I have 200 gb database .

Comment: Our Db is almost 15 GB, we don't have any problems yet

Comment: what about the cost ?